# How to change styles of nz-table in NG-Zorro

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

How to change styles of a nz-table in nz-zorro in angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s72Lg.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can override the ng-zorro ant design by **::ng-deep** keyword, for example:

```
::ng-deep .ant-table.ant-table-default 

    { 
          padding: 16px; 16px

    }
```

Comment: I had to do 
::ng-deep .ant-table table { }